# how to solve linear regression with conditions in R

Tags: r, regression

I would like to do a linear regression with conditions, like:
Y = a*x1 + b*x2 +c, a>0 , b <1 and c>=0

```
Y <- c(167, 136, 195, 174, 144, 135, 89, 81, 114, 111)
x1 <- c(2.9, 3.4, 0.7, 1.1, 3.5, 5.0, 6.7, 4.7, 3.7, 8.8)
X2 <- c(60, 47, 63, 62, 40, 60, 50, 35, 40, 40)
mydata <- data.frame(Y,X1,X2)
```

Is there an easy way to do this in R? .

Comment: Hi, people will be better able to help and more willing if you provide an example of your data and what sort of output you're looking for.  Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: You can solve linear regression problems with linear programming.  Here is a link to get you started: https://lazyprogrammer.me/linear-programming-for-linear-regression/  If your case, the constraints would be added to the standard regression formulation.  (Note: haven't tried added constraints myself).  Very useful linear programming packages in R are ROI and OMPR.  OMPR formulates the problem and calls ROI functions to solve it and report results.

Comment: I don't know how to write a least squares problem with restrictions as an LP. A QP would be more appropriate.

Comment: The reference on linear programming for linear regression is very misleading. Instead of least squares they use LAD which gives different results. Linear regression usually implies least squares. LAD regression is used in special cases (e.g. when robustness against outliers is required). LAD estimates are also not always unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you can do this with CVXR:

```
> library(CVXR)
> 
> #
> # data
> #
> Y <- c(167, 136, 195, 174, 144, 135, 89, 81, 114, 111)
> X1 <- c(2.9, 3.4, 0.7, 1.1, 3.5, 5.0, 6.7, 4.7, 3.7, 8.8)
> X2 <- c(60, 47, 63, 62, 40, 60, 50, 35, 40, 40)
> 
> #
> # organize as matrix
> #
> X <- cbind(1,X1,X2)
> X
         X1 X2
 [1,] 1 2.9 60
 [2,] 1 3.4 47
 [3,] 1 0.7 63
 [4,] 1 1.1 62
 [5,] 1 3.5 40
 [6,] 1 5.0 60
 [7,] 1 6.7 50
 [8,] 1 4.7 35
 [9,] 1 3.7 40
[10,] 1 8.8 40
> 
> 
> #
> # standard regression
> #
> lm(Y~X1+X2)

Call:
lm(formula = Y ~ X1 + X2)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)           X1           X2  
     82.616       -7.716        1.675  

> 
> #
> # standard regression as QP
> #
> beta <- Variable(3)
> 
> problem <- Problem(Minimize(sum_squares(Y - X %*% beta)))
> result <- solve(problem, verbose=T)
-----------------------------------------------------------------
           OSQP v0.6.0  -  Operator Splitting QP Solver
              (c) Bartolomeo Stellato,  Goran Banjac
        University of Oxford  -  Stanford University 2019
-----------------------------------------------------------------
problem:  variables n = 13, constraints m = 10
          nnz(P) + nnz(A) = 50
settings: linear system solver = qdldl,
          eps_abs = 1.0e-05, eps_rel = 1.0e-05,
          eps_prim_inf = 1.0e-04, eps_dual_inf = 1.0e-04,
          rho = 1.00e-01 (adaptive),
          sigma = 1.00e-06, alpha = 1.60, max_iter = 10000
          check_termination: on (interval 25),
          scaling: on, scaled_termination: off
          warm start: on, polish: on, time_limit: off

iter  objective    pri res    dua res    rho        time
   1   0.0000e+00   1.95e+02   1.70e+05   1.00e-01   3.47e-04s
  50   2.8959e+03   3.20e-07   2.29e-06   1.00e-01   8.43e-04s
plsh   2.8959e+03   4.21e-14   4.51e-13  ---------   1.36e-03s

status:               solved
solution polish:      successful
number of iterations: 50
optimal objective:    2895.8618
run time:             1.36e-03s
optimal rho estimate: 4.57e-02

> result$getValue(beta)
          [,1]
[1,] 82.616486
[2,] -7.716095
[3,]  1.674722
> 
> #
> # add constraints
> #      beta[1] >= 0       (constant term)
> #      beta[2] >= 0.0001  (instead of > we do >= with a small tolerance)
> #      beta[3] <= 0.9999  (instead of < we do <= with a small tolerance)
> #
> problem <- Problem(Minimize(sum_squares(Y - X %*% beta)),
+                    list(beta[1]>=0,
+                         beta[2]>=0.0001,
+                         beta[3]<=0.9999))
> result <- solve(problem, verbose=T)
-----------------------------------------------------------------
           OSQP v0.6.0  -  Operator Splitting QP Solver
              (c) Bartolomeo Stellato,  Goran Banjac
        University of Oxford  -  Stanford University 2019
-----------------------------------------------------------------
problem:  variables n = 13, constraints m = 13
          nnz(P) + nnz(A) = 53
settings: linear system solver = qdldl,
          eps_abs = 1.0e-05, eps_rel = 1.0e-05,
          eps_prim_inf = 1.0e-04, eps_dual_inf = 1.0e-04,
          rho = 1.00e-01 (adaptive),
          sigma = 1.00e-06, alpha = 1.60, max_iter = 10000
          check_termination: on (interval 25),
          scaling: on, scaled_termination: off
          warm start: on, polish: on, time_limit: off

iter  objective    pri res    dua res    rho        time
   1   0.0000e+00   1.95e+02   1.71e+05   1.00e-01   5.30e-04s
 150   7.8534e+03   9.37e-05   5.05e-04   4.62e+00   1.51e-03s
plsh   7.8533e+03   5.55e-14   2.84e-14  ---------   1.94e-03s

status:               solved
solution polish:      successful
number of iterations: 150
optimal objective:    7853.3365
run time:             1.94e-03s
optimal rho estimate: 2.98e+00

> result$getValue(beta)
         [,1]
[1,] 84.90456
[2,]  0.00010
[3,]  0.99990
>
```

Comment: Where are the constraints: a>0 , b <1 and c>=0?

Comment: See:  `list(beta[1]>=0, beta[2]>=0.0001, beta[3]<=0.9999)`